# AngularJS: how to use a factory with two-way data binding

Tags: angularjs

EDIT:
Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iInh7TnbGvSHSPOWuWPk?p=preview

====================================================================

In the following plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TIfkYE?p=preview

A very simple example compares the usage of a factory and a service. Two way data-binding works using the service but not the factory. Why?

With the service:

```
<button btn-radio="item.nb" ng-model="fromService.current>
```

clicking the button correctly updates the property current of the service fromService.

However, using a factory:

```
<button btn-radio="item.nb" ng-model="fromFactory.current>
```

clicking the button does not update the property current of the factory fromFactory.

My use case is the following: I want to use a service/factory to share data across controllers and other services.

I have read a lot references, including:

- http://iffycan.blogspot.be/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide
- https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232
- [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)
- http://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `var current` is a primitive and when you initialize the object using it as a value, it will not create a reference to intial variable, the object property will just take it's value.

WIthin your `isCurrent` function you are then making comparison to the original variable, which never changes. The `current` property however is changed by the 2 way binding you created with `ng-model`

Simple example ( can paste this in your browser console to confirm):

```
var current=0;
var obj={
  current: current
}

current=10;
alert(obj.current)// hasn't changed, is still 0
```

To fix your factory you need to make your comparisons to the object returned from factory

```
myApp.factory('fromFactory', function() {
  console.log("factory is called");
    var current = 0;
    return {
        current: current,
        isCurrent: function (nb) {

           /* change return nb === current;*/

          /* compare to the object version of "current" which is bound to ng-model*/
          return nb === this.current;
          },
        printCurrent: function () {
          console.log("print fromFactory", this.current);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Solution is to construct an object and return it:

```
myApp.factory('fromFactory', function() {

    console.log("factory is called");

    var exports = {};
    exports.current = 0;
    exports.isCurrent = function (nb) {
          return nb == exports.current;
    };
    exports.printCurrent = function () {
        console.log("print fromFactory", exports.current);
    };

    return exports;
});
```

Both this and charlietfl solutions work perfectly.
Working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iInh7TnbGvSHSPOWuWPk?p=preview

Comment: this returns same thing, just different syntax adding properties to object `return  {}` means return object